# VM Budget Android checkouts Problems

Tags: android

Hallo, there are a lot of stuff with "bitmap size exceeds VM budget".but where can I check the problems to see when it happens. I programm a sprite based game and use a lot of picture (not too big but a lot). The game works fine on the htc desire but on a hero i get this  bitmap size exceeds vm budget problms. So where can I chek how much is already allocated or in use? The DDMS? and when where? Is there an Overview how much memory each telephon can use for pictures?  So i need an overview when i prepare mycode that I can chek the result of my efforts. HopeI was clearly, sorry for mybad english.

Thank You for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similiar question : [How to tell how close your activity is to reaching its memory limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943468/how-to-tell-how-close-your-activity-is-to-reaching-its-memory-limit)