# Application.onLowMemory() not invloked

Tags: android, callback, low-memory

I've create an Application class of my own.

I try to debug it and the code stops at Application.onCreate() but does not stop at onLowMemory.

To test the scenario I open a lot of other high memory applications.

What I see is that the debug session terminated (in eclipse) and some of my static variables turned to null - indicates the the process has ended.

Not only did the debug NOT stop @ the breakpoint of the method, I've put a Log.e(...) line and don't see it as well.

Any idea of why the method was not invoked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there are any guarantees that this method will ever be called.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29):

> While the exact point at which this
>   will be called is not defined,
>   generally it will happen around the
>   time all background process have been
>   killed, that is before reaching the
>   point of killing processes hosting
>   service and foreground UI that we
>   would like to avoid killing.

Since the point at which it is called is not defined, it could choose to never call it.

In general, Android is free to kill your Application whenever it wants, as long as it is in the background.  You should only rely on methods in the lifecycle (like onPause, onStop, onDestroy) that specifically state that they are guaranteed to be called in order to do any necessary cleanup.

Comment: Thanks Mayra. Do you know of another way to get a callback of the application being destroyed? Currently, for each activity (using inheritance), I validate the status of the app by checking a static variable being null.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a way to know for sure when an Application is destroyed.  You can just find out that individual Activities have been destroyed.  However, if onCreate is called on your Application then you know that it was destroyed at some point in the past, so you can do whatever reloading you need to do then.