# Application class gets recreated after opening some other applications

Tags: java, android, singleton

I'm new at developing Android. I'm experiencing the following problem:

I'm working on a Android application that extends the Application class. The values for the authentication session are stored in this class, because it is supposed to get created once and it is available in all activitys and services.

When I open my application and close it with the home button, and reopen it after I opened a lot of other apps, the base application class gets recreated (onCreate gets called). When this happens, I lose my authentication values. It seems like it that the onTerminate or onLowMemory are not getting called before the onCreate is getting called again. The current state of my application is not gone, because the previously active activity is still available.

When I close the app with the home button and only open a few other apps, the application resumes normally.

I also tried to implement a singleton class, but the singleton object is also null if the application class gets recreated.

How can I prevent the recreation of the application class, or work around this problem?

Thanks
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the application class can also be restarted as part of the application lifecycle. I stored my authentication values in preferences to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of [Application.onTerminate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()):

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never
> be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed
> by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is
> executed when doing so.

Also there is no guarantee that `onLowMemory` will be called. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330475/1140997).

> The current state of my application is not gone, because the
> previously active activity is still available.

I think activity is just restored from Bundle.

> How can I prevent the recreation of the application class, or work
> around this problem?

You have to be ready that you application can be recreted in any moment. You can store some data in this class but before grab this data from some activity you should check if it is null. It will be null in first start and after application recreating. Just fill it with your data and return to activity.