# Android max image/texture resolution

Tags: android, image, image-size

I did a quick google search, but I couldn't find the max image/texture resolution for android. I currently have an image that is crashing , but when I lower the resolution it works. I dont want to just trial and error the resolutions to see if it works, some solid numbers showing limitations would be ideal.

A link to the android documentation would be fine as well. I personally don't find it intuitive.

Comment: Which do you want to know? Drawable image or OpenGL Texture? If the latter, it would be depend on the hardware.

Comment: What kind of exception are you seeing thrown?

Comment: Another post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573178/limitation-on-texture-size-android-open-gl-es-2-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it fails at a high resolution but works with a lower resolution, it sounds to me like you might be hitting a memory limit.

Have a look at this post on [Image memory cost](http://www.scantips.com/basics1d.html)

```
1200 dpi - 7200x4800  (34,560,000 pixels)  - 103,680,000 bytes (99 MB)
2400 dpi - 14400x9600 (138,240,000 pixels) - 414,720,000 bytes (396 MB)
```

If you are pushing into the range of 130 million pixels, you are well over on your (fair) memory consumption, at least on most of today's mobile hardware.

**UPDATE**

Here is another post discussing [issues related to photos and memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131947/android-memory-allocation)

Comment: I believe that is it more likely that he was hitting the texture size limit, not out of memory errors.