# How to find out maximum bitmap size to be loaded into an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory, android-photoview

I have an [app](https://github.com/k3b/AndroFotoFinder/) that can among others zoom 
images using [chris bane's PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).

When i load large images i get "OutOfMemoryError"

When i add this

```
     <application ... android:largeHeap="true">
```

to AndroidManifest.xml

I get a more specific error message with my android-4.4 device

```
    Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (7087x1022, max=4096x4096)
```

My question: is there an api (or something else) that tells me that my current android device has a limit of 4096x4096 ?

Comment: you can query the `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` from the runtime environment using `glGetIntegerv`. There's a code sample in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8573543/49489

Comment: this may help you - http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: @Saket Mittal: the training explains how to scale down and how to find out image size in bytes (hight*with*4) but not how to caclulate maxWidth and maxHeight which i was asking for.