# Android Studio Libgdx Black Texture

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures

I put a texture as a background with 720 width and 8140 height and I am drawing it as a background without stretching it. It appears black, but on another phone it was fine. Other textures are fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many GPUs simply cannot load a texture with a width or height greater than 2048. You can [query the max size supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573543/506796) at runtime, but that would only be useful if you have a backup plan for devices that cannot support the size you want. I think it would be easier to have one design based on the 2048 limit.

Comment: So if I split the texture in something like 4 or 5 parts, it will be fine, right?