# ImageView not showing large images when targeting api level 14 (ICS) or greater

Tags: android, imageview

An ImageView in my app which normally displays OK has recently disappeared after I changed the target SDK version. After some trial and error, I have found that the image displays fine when I set `android:targetSdkVersion="13"` but not `android:targetSdkVersion="14"`

I have also noticed that other images display fine. Furthermore, if I resize my image to be smaller, the smaller image displays ok.

Has anything changed between API levels 13 and 14 which would explain this?

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation, I found that the size limit for displaying the resized image is a width of 2048 pixels.

It seems that in API level 14 (ICS) and above, a restriction has been placed on the maximum dimensions of images. After this API change, images are no longer allowed with a width or height greater than 2048. The restriction apparently arises from the underlying openGL implementation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314838/1346778)