# How to load a high resolution Bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, size, resolution

I'm working on an android app, and in resources folder I have an image which is `8000x400px` resolution. It is a `.png` that I'm using at my `Sprite` class to simulate the movement of an animal.

I display the portion of the `png` using `drawBitmap()` in my `SurfaceView` class.

Sprite class, SurfaceView and all the elements work perfect, but when working with that large images it doesnt display anything.

**To fix this problem I would like to know.**

1. What is the limit of maximum resolution of a Bitmap allowed in
   Android?
2. How could I display in `onDraw()` a Sprite with that size?

Answer (score 2):

**Concerning the displaying / loading of Bitmaps:**

You need to load the `Bitmap` properly and **adjust the size** of the `Bitmap` to your needs. In most cases, it makes no sense to load a Bitmap with higher resolution than the screen of the device supports.

Furthermore, this practice is very important to avoid `OutOfMemoryErrors` when working with `Bitmaps` that large.

As an example, a Bitmap with the size of 8000 x 4000 uses more than **100 Megabytes** of RAM (in 32 Bit color), which is an enormous amount for a mobile device and much more than even high end devices are capable of handling.

This is how to **load a Bitmap properly:**

```
public abstract class BitmapResLoader {

    public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    private static int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Example usage in code:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapResLoader.decodeBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
                                                      R.drawable.mybitmap, 500, 500);
```

Taken from the Google Android Developer guidelines here: 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

**Concerning the maximum Bitmap size:**

The maximum Bitmap size limit **depends on the unterlying OpenGL implementation**. When using OpenGL, this can be tested via (source: [Android : Maximum allowed width & height of bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313807/android-maximum-allowed-width-height-of-bitmap)):

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```

e.g. for the Galaxy S2, it is 2048x2048.