# How to display very long Bitmaps in Android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

Suppose you have an image that measures 500x6000 pixels. I tried loading such an image in my Android app but soon found out that there are maximum dimensions for bitmaps (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313807/android-maximum-allowed-width-height-of-bitmap))

Now, I still would like to be able to show such an image. How can I do that?

I could just simply adjust the height. But since the image has only 500px in width the resolution becomes poor really quick.

Comment: Is slicing an option? For example show 10 x 500x600 bitmaps within a vertical LinearLayout?

Comment: as a last resort ... yes, maybe. just would like to know if there any best practices for such a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the reason [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) exists - it allows you to decode just a portion of a larger image at a time.

However, it does imply that you know the exact regions you wish to decode and how to tile/scroll images together as needed.

Comment: Hi! I have same problem. But. I need to load very large image.jpg(750x7400) into ImageView(which wrapped by ScrollView). I need whole image to make scrolling it.. How can I achive this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @researcher - you can try something like [this library](https://github.com/diegocarloslima/ByakuGallery) which a Google search for 'bitmapregiondecoder example' brings up :)

Comment: Thanks for response! But I have already tried this library( It's not what I want..

Comment: @researcher - then you'll have to build something yourself on top of `BitmapRegionDecoder`.

Comment: Ok, thanks:) I'll try to do smth with BitmapRegionDecoder.