# how to create large bitmap 5000 X 5000

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I was working through the following [tutorial](http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2013/06/image-with-zoom-and-paint-on-zoomed.html), I need to create a bitmap with the following code:

```
cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

the width/height can be greater than 5000 , but that would cause an OOM error. I tried to create a seperate thread but that didnt work. Is this even possible ? Does createBitmap have a limit for width/height ?

Comment: see this link this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313807/android-maximum-allowed-width-height-of-bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your AppManifest.xml in your application tag this code:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

This will try to prevent your app from causing OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: I did not know about this. A link to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap) for the lazy.

Comment: this will not prevent your app from crashing because of a large bitmap

Comment: @tyczj It will try to prevent the app from crashing, but not on devices with such low memory. I know that... But that should at least help him.