# Android ViewPager using SubsamplingScaleImageView results in blank screen for sometime when sliding images

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, subsampling

I have made a ViewPager using [davemorrissey's SubsamplingScaleImageView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)

When sliding the ViewPager, the next slide appears to be blank for some seconds before the image loads.

Has anyone faced same type of issue ? Any pointers for possible fixes ?

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
magePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();       
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

ArrayList<String> imageFull = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
String image = "mnt/sdcard/imageDemo"+i+".jpg";
imageFull.add(image);
}


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      Context context = ImageGallery.this;

      SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);
      fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position)));         

      return fullImage;
   }


   @Override
   public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);

   }
```

Comment: That is a SubsamplingScaleImageView function to set Image from SD card as background in a SubsamplingScaleImageView. Details here - https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: imageFull is actually an Arraylist of type String. I'm editing the question.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your precious time. I'm trying to understand and apply your answer to my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to workaround it with [this patch](https://github.com/inorichi/subsampling-scale-image-view/commit/e84f287885f7cb0e55a1371f9dcd42196550ce97). I also wrote a similar answer in the [visibility problem issue](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/issues/127)

`initialiseBaseLayer` is called the first `onDraw` of the view, that's why it doesn't load until the page is partially visible.

The issue is that initializing outside `onDraw` you lose access to the canvas, which is used to calculate the max bitmap dimensions:

```
private Point getMaxBitmapDimensions(Canvas canvas) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        try {
            int maxWidth = (Integer)Canvas.class.getMethod("getMaximumBitmapWidth").invoke(canvas);
            int maxHeight = (Integer)Canvas.class.getMethod("getMaximumBitmapHeight").invoke(canvas);
            return new Point(maxWidth, maxHeight);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Return default
        }
    }
    return new Point(2048, 2048);
}
```

So, you will have to provide the max dimensions on your own. I'm using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26823209/3263582). I store the value during the `onCreate` of the activity and later the ViewPager get that value.

Before setting the image call `fullImage.setMaxDimensions(x, y)` and that's it.

It works fine (in my case) for a ViewPager, but it doesn't on a RecyclerView, so use it with care.

Answer (score 2):

Your Screen is black cause the image is not decoded yet.

**You can use:**

```
public final void setImage(ImageSource imageSource, ImageSource previewSource)
```

and use a thumbnail as preview. The preview is shown until the decoding of the image is finished.

**Note that:**

the Preview image cannot be used unless dimensions are provided for the main image.

**No tested but something like:**

```
Uri uri = imageFull.get(position);
Bitmap preview = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                             getContentResolver(), uri,
                             MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                             null);

ImageSource src = ImageSource.uri(uri);
src .dimensions(w, h); // if you don't know the size, you can just decode the bounds of your image which is quite fast

fullImage.setImage(src , ImageSource.bitmap(preview));
```

If generation of the Thumbnail is to slow for you, feel free to do that in an AsyncTask.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit ? How to use it with the ViewPager code ?