# Xamarin Image background Not Showing on Android

Tags: android, image, xaml, xamarin

I try to create an application sample with Xamarin using XAML et Visual Studio. 
For exemple, the following code is InitPage.xaml.

> ```
> <RelativeLayout>
>     <Image Source="baseandroid.png" 
>            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width}"
>            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height}"/>
>     <Grid RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width}"
>           RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height}">
>
>         <Label FontSize="14" Text="test" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100"
> ```
>
> />

baseandroid.png can be found in Android > Ressources > Drawable

But i can't display image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jrug.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms image not showing-Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426950/xamarin-forms-image-not-showing-android)

Answer (score 1):

In your xaml code, you are setting the Image within the RelativeLayout outside the ContentPage.Content tag. You must place it inside the ConetntPage.Content.