# Image load in imageView from gallery become black

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, uri

So I load image from galley and display into `ImageView`, the image turn to black. But not all images, just a certain. Why would this happen?

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {

        case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                imageUri = data.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
            break;
         }
     }
```

Then I tried this method. The image show but look blurry.

```
 imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeUri(imageUri));

 private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it happens when `Bitmap` can't be loaded because the height and width of the image is larger in size which is `2048*2048`. Images captured through camera are usually large in size so, It is good practice to resize the image.

**Below is just an example to crop image if large in size,and does not take care of image ratio**

```
public class InputImageCompressor extends Activity{

public static void compressInputImage(Intent data, Context context, ImageView newIV)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Uri inputImageData = data.getData();
    try
    {
        Bitmap bitmapInputImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), inputImageData);
        if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
        {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);
            newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
        {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1920, 1200, true);
            newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
        {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);
            newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
        {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, bitmapInputImage.getWidth(), bitmapInputImage.getHeight(), true);
            newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
}
```

Use this in your `onActivityResult` as:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

    case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
             InputImageCompressor.compressInputImage(data, your_activity_context.this, imageView);
        }
        break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that the common 2048x2048 limit is due to a limit on OpenGL rendering on android.  Note that it's not always 2048x2048, it depends on the device.  Details are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313807/android-maximum-allowed-width-height-of-bitmap

Answer (score 1):

The code looks alright, the fact that you are seeing a blurry image sort of confirms that too.

I think the REQUIRED_SIZE is too small for the device you are trying. For starters, try setting the REQUIRED_SIZE to something bigger, e.g. 350 and see if it improves the image quality. If it does, then instead of statically putting a "size", use `REQUIRED_SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH`

To find SCREEN_WIDTH, use the following, from within an Activity (or at least a view):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int SCREEN_WIDTH = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```