# Big images resolution on android are not drawn

Tags: java, android, image, libgdx

I have images with 5000x4000 px resolution (GUI graphics) and take from it Texture Regions of size about 200 x 200(they are buttons). When i build this project for desktop everything is okay whereas built for android is not... Instead of images only black canvas are drawn.

Comment: Sizes greater than 2048 are not supported on all Android devices.

Comment: you can't render that big image on Android as every device has it's own limitation of rendering bitmap. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314838/1852343