# Android Splash screen does not display

Tags: android, splash-screen

The splash screen in my app does not display.Only a white backgound is shown. Then it goes to the next page.I have seen other similar questions in stackoverflow but it did not help me.
splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        },2000);

    }
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your `Manifest.xml`

Comment: ok.will do it now

Comment: Manifest included.Please look into it

Comment: i think you are trying to load big sized image. @drawable/splash. try  some other image instead of splash image

Comment: Ok. I will try now

Comment: @jobin are you sure you have define `splash` in `Drawable` folder.

Comment: @Ahmed.Yes it worked when I used another image

Comment: So is it because of the size of the image(114.59K)

Comment: Try low sized image.  Or down sample the existing image

Comment: Please see the below links for more help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487124/android-splash-screen-sizes-for-ldpi-mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi-displays-eg-1024x76

Comment: I reduced the image size to 41.75k. But it still did not work

Comment: @jobin is there any warnings in logcat regarding the image like  _Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture_?

Comment: Oh...yes...Now I notice.So what should I do

Comment: @jobin I think u need to keep different images in different drawable folders and reduce the size of image a little more and try

Comment: @jobin post that warning as well?

Comment: I reduced it to 41.75k earlier

Comment: W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3000x5314, max=4096x4096)

Comment: @jobin try the soln here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154031/load-big-size-image-issue-in-imageview-bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a

Comment: added solution. try it . its worked on me already. i faced same error at first.

Comment: Your solution worked.But it does not fill the entire screen,So I set scaleType=fitXY to ImageView. Now it fills the enitre screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When Big sized image you should downsample the image. change the inSampleSize variable value as per your need. increased value, will reduce the image resolution and vise versa

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
  }

private static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

call above methods like below code:

```
  decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.splash, 400, 400);
```

just, add above methods in your common helper class and call it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is something i faced when creating splash screens. You start the handler in the onCreate method of the activity.

According to the android developer [site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

> When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it

So you are creating a handler on the main thread which is also responsible for the UI. This thread prepares your UI (which in this case seems to take a bit more than 2 seconds) and then calls the Runnable inside your handler which immediately moves to another activity thus your splash is not shown.

So what could you do? Start the timer after your view is shown!!!

This is how you can do it (Probably not the only way but good enough):

1- Set an id for the RelativeLayout in the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash">
</RelativeLayout>
```

2- In your onCreate method do like this:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        View background = findViewById(R.id.background); // or use Butterknife or DataBinding for ease of use
        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        background.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        },2000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This way you post a message to the view message queue and after the view is put on the screen then it registers a handler as you wish. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I tried to solve your problem

**splash_screen_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splashscreen">

</LinearLayout>
```

**SplashScreenActivity.java**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_activity);

        Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                    sleep(5*1000);

                    // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //Remove activity
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        background.start();
    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pantrykart">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```