# Android memory leak detection using MAT

Tags: android

I am trying to analyze the heap dump of my android app. The analyzer MAT shows 
me this message

The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "", occupies 12,084,776 (87.38%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "".

What do I do about this? I want to avoid OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: have you checked the size of the drawables you use in the app. I came across a similar situation and the issue in my case was the size of the drawables

Comment: its 2.23MB. How do you know its more or less?

Comment: 2.23MB for single drawable,then its way too much
100-150 KB(at the max per drawable) will be descent one I hope

Answer (score 1):

As almuneef mentioned, this is mostly seen when the size of your resources is large. Are you trying to load a bitmap? 
You might want to look at [Android memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131947/android-memory-allocation)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the large resources. Just reduce the size of your resources and your issue will be fixed.
If your resources are in .png format then change it to jpeg and you can easily reduce the quality of the image (size also reduces considerably for even a small loss in quality)
Hope this will fix your out of memory issues

Answer (score 0):

Don’t worry about “android.content.res.Resources”，It was loaded by system，